# Physical location of Philosopher's Stone before Harry's pocket?

Tags: harry-potter, philosophers-stone

Timeline:

1. Gringotts vault 713
2. Hagrid's coat
3. ???
4. Harry's pocket

It was destroyed *after* this, so presumably still *existed*. Was Quirrel's guess of it being *inside* the Mirror of Erised correct?

Can't be physically, because then breaking it *would* have yielded the stone, and Quirrel wouldn't've had to "use the boy"

Inside a mirror dimension? Inside the mirror as a *concept* instead of a physical object? But the stone must still physically *be* somewhere, no?

Comment: Magic doesn't follow the rules of physics. We have bags and tents that are bigger on the inside. Cabinets that transport you between each of them instantly. Turning people into animals.... The stone is in the mirror, magically.

Comment: There's a quote from Quirrell/Voldemort, something about 'Is the stone inside? Do I have to break it?'

Answer (score 2):

The stone was probably in the room and probably under a spell that will cause you not to find it (kind of like the Fidelius Charm). Dumbledore then enchanted the stone to appear only in the pocket of a person whose deepest desire was to find the stone, but not use it. The Mirror of Erised was there to determine what your desire was.

> "How did I get the Stone out of the mirror?"
> "Ah, now, I'm glad you asked me that. It was one of my more brilliant ideas, and between you and me, that's saying something. You see, only one who wanted to find the Stone — find it, but not use it — would be able to get it, otherwise they'd just see themselves making gold or drinking Elixir of Life. My brain surprises even me sometimes..."

Dumbledore says the stone was there, but only if you wanted to find it and not use it.
Quirrell focused on the mirror, but didn't realise it was only the path to get to the stone. Breaking the mirror wouldn't help — the stone would only reveal itself under very specific conditions.

In short: Dumbledore put the stone in a condition that will cause it to appear only in the pocket of the seeker who's deepest desire was to retrieve the stone but not use it.

Comment: Dumbledore's response heavily implies the stone **was** inside the mirror.

Comment: Why the pocket?

Comment: @SovereignSun: Maybe Dumbledore likes pockets? :)

Comment: @Jontia- not at all. Dumbledore says If someone saw himself in the mirror finding the stone- He'll be able to get it. The mirror didn't contain the stone, it was a way of determining if you're worthy of it.

Comment: Geographically in the room does seem like the likely answer, but I don't see great evidence for that yet. The question is perhaps better expressed as "What coordinates would a GPS-tracker show?" (Taking into account that electronics go haywire in Hogwarts). - Related or replacement question: Why didn't/couldn't Quirrel/Voldemort break the enchantment Dumbledore had cast on Erised?

Comment: @Jonta We don't know exactly where in the room it was located. nobody ever says that in the books.

Comment: @MBEllis I know it doesn't say in the books. Hence my question. I'm not nearly as familiar with Pottermore and other sources as other people are, thus my asking here. =)